# Where to host a Python script?

Tags: python, cloud

I know this is a very basic question but I'm struggling. I'm at the point where I know what I'd like to do but don't know exactly what to Google to get there.

I have a small python script that runs through a csv, using each row in an API call, and then adds rows to another csv when a certain response is given by the API. I'm currently just running it in the terminal.

I want to start running it constantly but don't want to leave my computer on with it running in the background. I'm assuming there's a service that would let me 'host' the script along with the necessary csv files but I don't know what to search to find it.

What is the best service to perform what I need for minimal cost?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Requests for us to find or recommend off-site resources, like hosts, are explicitly _off-topic_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Heroku](https://heroku.com/) would be an option. Another option is to use [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) platform

Pythonanywhere is free provided you log in once in three months.

Heroku free tier might have limitations in storing large csv files. But you can use cloud storage(like aws s3 etc.) if you have large files.

If you want to do some serious stuff for a long time you can explore all cloud providers like Google Cloud, Axure, AWS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Linux EC2 instance in the AWS Free Tier: https://aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier/

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If you want a stable publicly available server you should indeed look for a hosting service, in which case I can't answer your question as I don't know any. However, if you are only interested in having the program constantly running and/or you only need to serve a small amount of clients, I'd suggest buying a raspberry pi, they are quite cheap and flexible and you can easily set up a tiny server at home.